# the object doesn't accept property or method

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I have this function in my scripts and Internet Explorer throws an error:
"el objeto no acepta la propiedad o el metodo trunc" which means something like "the object doesn't accept property or method trunc"

```
function minutesToString(a){
  var hours = Math.trunc(a/60);
  var minutes = a % 60;
  return(hours +" hr "+ minutes + " m");
}
```

On chrome, firefox, etc. works perfectly.

Comment: IE does not support Math.trunc()

Comment: @Quentin the question is obvious. Thanks for the info anyways

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Add a polyfill for `Math.trunc()`. Include the following code somewhere before using `Math.trunc()`

```
Math.trunc = Math.trunc || function(x) {
  if (isNaN(x)) {
    return NaN;
  }
  if (x > 0) {
    return Math.floor(x);
  }
  return Math.ceil(x);
};
```

Comment: This is a workaround to get it to work which should help here but the issue is IE.  It doesn't support the trunc property on the Math Object.  You can prototype the Math Object to include it yourself.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. Unlike people like @Quentin you actually helped with a solution instead of going for my broking english. Regards

Answer (score 2):

Simply use Math.floor instead or leave it away completely:

```
function minutesToString(a){
 var minutes = a % 60;
 var hours=(a-minutes)/60;
 return(hours +" hr "+ minutes + " m");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/trunc#Browser_compatibility

This is the MDN, and you can look up JS functions here.  On the right there is a browser compatibility section or at the bottom of the page.  Considering IE sucks, it doesn't support this property (trunc) on the Math object.

Answer (score 0):

`parseInt()` accepts numbers, is supported by IE and behaves just like Math.trunc